# How to generate k-itemset for apriori algorithm in python

Tags: python, tuples, apriori

this is the first time I am trying to code in python and I am implementing the Apriori algorithm. I have generated till 2-itemsets and below is the function I have to generate 2-Itemsets by combining the keys of the 1-itemset.

How do I go about making this function generic? I mean, by passing the keys of a dictionary and the number of elements required in the tuple, the algorithm should generate all possible n-number(k+1) subsets using the keys. I know that Union on sets is a possibility, but is there a way to do union of tuples which is essentially the keys of a dictionary?

```
# generate 2-itemset candidates by joining the 1-itemset candidates
def candidate_gen(keys):
    adict={}
    for i in keys:
        for j in keys:
            #if i != j and (j,i) not in adict:
            if j>i:
        #call join procedure which will generate f(k+1) keys
        #call has_infrequent_subset --> generates all possible k+1 itemsets and checks if k itemsets are present in f(k) keys
                adict[tuple([min(i,j),max(i,j)])] = 0
    return adict
```

For example, if my initial dictionary looks like: {key, value} --> value is the frequency

```
{'382': 1163, '298': 560, '248': 1087, '458': 720, 
 '118': 509,  '723': 528, '390': 1288}
```

I take the keys of this dictionary and pass it to the candidate_gen function mentioned above
it will generate the subsets of 2-itemsets and give the output of keys. I will then pass the keys to a function to find the frequency by comparing against the original database to get this output:

```
{('390', '723'): 65, ('118', '298'): 20, ('298', '390'): 70, ('298', '458'): 35, 
 ('248', '382'): 88, ('248', '458'): 76, ('248', '723'): 26, ('382', '723'): 203,
 ('390', '458'): 33, ('118', '458'): 26, ('458', '723'): 26, ('248', '390'): 87,
 ('118', '248'): 54, ('298', '382'): 47, ('118', '723'): 41, ('382', '390'): 413,
 ('382', '458'): 57, ('248', '298'): 64, ('118', '382'): 40, ('298', '723'): 36, 
 ('118', '390'): 52}
```

How do I generated 3-itemset subsets from the above keys.

Comment: Can you give some example input and the expected output? This will make your problem much clearer for everyone.

Comment: Your code has  `if j>i: adict[tuple([min(i,j),max(i,j)])] = 0` but it's equivalent to the simpler `if j>i: adict[i,j]=0`

Comment: In your code, `keys` are strings and the comparison `j>i` works if the strings are of the same length. Please try `print('oh!' if '99'>'100' else 'ok.')` at the interpreter prompt...

Answer (score 1):

I assume that, given your field, you can benefit very much from the study of python's [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) library.

In your use case you can directly use the itertools `combinations`
or wrap it in a helper function

```
from itertools import combinations
def ord_comb(l,n):
    return list(combinations(l,n))

#### TESTING ####
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(ord_comb(a,1))
print(ord_comb(a,5))
print(ord_comb(a,6))
print(ord_comb([],2))
print(ord_comb(a,3))
```

**Output**

```
[(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,)]
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)]
[]
[]
[(1, 2, 3), (1, 2, 4), (1, 2, 5), (1, 3, 4), (1, 3, 5), (1, 4, 5), (2, 3, 4), (2, 3, 5), (2, 4, 5), (3, 4, 5)]
```

Please note that the order of the elements in the `n`-uples depends on the order that you used in the iterable that you pass to `combinations`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. This will give n-number combinations over a list containing a = [1,2,3,4,5] --> single elements. say if my input was a = [(1,2),(3,4),(1,5)] and so on. How to generate n-number combinations over that? like,
output --> a= [(1,2,3),(1,2,4)...,(1,2,5)] an so on.

Comment: @prakyathj, the last case in my `TESTING` code, isn't it what you're looking for? In your example the level 2 tuples were in number of 21, that is ((7x8)/2-7) all the non repeating combinations of the original 7 items taken 2 by 2, so I deduced (no expertise in apriori algorithms) that you need all the distinct, ordered combinations of 3 items from the original seven... If for level 3 you need something different from these combinations, please tell me because I can't understand.

Comment: @prakyathj I'd like to stress that the last line in the box labeled **Output** up there in my answer is _exactly_ what _you_ wrote, in terms of an unsatisfied requirement, in the end of your previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
In [12]: [(x, y) for x in keys for y in keys if y>x]
Out[12]: 
[('382', '723'),
 ('382', '458'),
 ('382', '390'),
 ('458', '723'),
 ('298', '382'),
 ('298', '723'),
 ('298', '458'),
 ('298', '390'),
 ('390', '723'),
 ('390', '458'),
 ('248', '382'),
 ('248', '723'),
 ('248', '458'),
 ('248', '298'),
 ('248', '390'),
 ('118', '382'),
 ('118', '723'),
 ('118', '458'),
 ('118', '298'),
 ('118', '390'),
 ('118', '248')]
```

Comment: OP requires a 3rd level combination, as in `[ (x, y, z) for x in l for y in l for z in l if x < y < z]` so you're close.  If he needs deeper levels `(4, ..., n)` imho it's better a function like `itertools.combinations`

Comment: if he need deeper level and flexibility then yes.  
the code he pasted generates 2-itemsets